# Create a single number data frame with column names given in a list parameter

Tags: r, dataframe, namespaces

I have a list  of names generated by code `ldf.names <- lapply(ldf, colnames)`
ldf.names, mode(ldf.names) return "list" type data, it looks like this

```
[[1]]

 [1] "BAW01A" "BAW01B" "BAW03A" "BAW03B" 

[[2]]

 [1] "CHN01A" "CHN01B" "CHN02A" "CHN02B" 

[[3]]

 [1] "DAO01A" "DAO01B" "DAO01C" "DAO02A"
```

now I Need to create a new data.frame with the row names coming from ldf.names, the data are all 1. the new data frame should keep the same multi-dimension structure like ldf.names, anyone knows how to do this?

Comment: this id what I did , maybe looks too stupid:  n <- sum(as.numeric(summary(ldf.names)[,1]))
ones <- t(t(rep(1,n)))
po1 <- lapply(data.frame(ones), names, idf.names)  then I found error:Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : 
  2 arguments passed to 'names' which requires 1

Comment: Can you add your expected output?